# 2d движки на golang или как делать просчёт координат на сервере?

Tags: canvas, golang, 2d

Есть клиент- у него есть шарик с координатами.
Он хочет переместиться в другую область канваса за определённое время.
Просчёт должен сделать сервер. Тоесть сервер знает, что клиент1 сейчас находится в координатах х=20;y=50 а клиент навёл мышкой на область х=120;y=150, тоесть отправил серверу-"хочу туда".
Сервер должен,скажем, за 2 секунды переместить Клиента1 в ту точку, если от клиента не будет новых указаний и каждые,скажем,100мс сообщать координаты Клиента1. Тоесть клиент только отрисовывает то,что прислал сервер и говорит-куда хочу. Подобное есть в игре http://agar.io/
Как вообще на golang делать подобные просчёты?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть так же, как и на любом другом языке.

(x1, y1) - начальные координаты в момент времени t1.
(x2, y2) - конечные координаты в момент времени t2.
Нужно вычислить координаты(x0, y0) в момент времени t0.
Для этого мы должны к начальному значению по каждой из осей прибавить расстояние, которое нужно пройти по этой оси, помноженное на коэффициент прошедшего времени (в вашем случае это 2сек/(n*100мс) где n - номер шага).

```
y0 = y1+(y2-y1)*((t0-t1)/(t2-t1));
x0 = x1+(x2-x1)*((t0-t1)/(t2-t1));
```

- `(t0-t1)/(t2-t1)` -- это коэффициент пройдённого пути.
  Если t1 < t0 < t2, то он будет от 0 до 1.
- `(x2-x1)` -- расстояние по оси, которое нужно пройти
- `x1` -- начальное значение.